# How can I solve this css behaviour?

Tags: css, css-selectors, css-variables

I would like to make a stack css class, where every element which is followed by an element has a `margin-top`, like:

```
.stack > * + *{
    margin-top:var(--stack-gap);
}
```

now, with the `--stack-gap` var I can set a stack spacing. Like:

```css
.stack > * + * {
  margin-top: var(--stack-gap);
}
```

```html
<div class="stack" style="--stack-gap:20px">
  <div>...</div>
  <div>...</div>
</div>
```

So, between the two div tags there is a 20px space.

But when there is a stack class inside a class stack, and set the `--stack-gap` individually, then the parent `--stack-gap` property gets ignored as it set on the child stack. Like:

```css
.stack > * + * {
  margin-top: var(--stack-gap);
}
```

```html
<div class="stack" style="--stack-gap:20px">
  <div>
    <div>...</div>
    <div>...</div>
  </div>
  <div class="stack" style="--stack-gap:60px">
    <div>...</div>
    <div>...</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Now, the inner stack class has a `60px` margin top as it sets the `--stack-gap` to `60px`, but the expected behavior would be `20px` `margin-top` as I set the `--stack-gap` to `20px` on the parent stack.

I fully understand why it is happening, I just would like to ask how could I solve this problem, so the `--stack-gap` property on the stack element only affects the child elements, but not itself?

Comment: Could this selector be changed to `.stack > *:not(:first-child)`?

Comment: @JavascriptDev yes, its the same, so it doesnt change anything.

Comment: Try `.stack > .stack { margin-top: inherit; }`, which will make nested stacks inherit the parent margin, and hopefully solve your issue.

Comment: @chriskirknielsen then the inner stack wont get any margin-top because on the parent stack does not have any margin-top :( and it supposed to be 20px.

Comment: Ah, yes, of course… It would only work if the top-level parent had a margin to begin with. Didn't think this one through, did I? Sorry about that.

Comment: no problem mate, thank you for helping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for the answers, but i think ive found the simplest approach to this. I'll use grid and the grid-gap property(i would go with a column flex and the gap property but this is only implemented in firefox as of now). So i'll use the next class:

```
.stack{
    display:grid;
    grid-gap:var(--stack-gap);
}
```

with this solution i can set the --stack-gap individually and there wont be any conflicts.

Answer (score 0):

How many different variants of `--stack-gap` are you planning on? The most straightforward way to approach this would be to not use variables at all, and just create classes for each variant:

```css
.stack-20 > * + * {
  margin-top: 20px;
}
.stack-40 > * + * {
  margin-top: 40px;
}
.stack-60 > * + * {
  margin-top: 60px;
}
```

```html
<div class="stack-20">
   <div>
       <div>...</div>
       <div>...</div>
   </div>
   <div class="stack-60">
       <div>...</div>
       <div>...</div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Trying to solve this with a variable approach may be overcomplicating things.

Comment: Thank you for answer. Its a way to go, but im looking for a solution where any number would work.

Answer (score 0):

I tweaked a bit the HTML structure by adding a `.stack__inner` so that the selectors will actually cover the desired elements with the margin-top property.

Your previous selector didn't match the 2 firsts `<div>...</div>` you had. That's because your selector was applying `margin-top` to : **Any element being a direct child of a `.stack` element**.

But as your 2 firsts `<div>...</div>` are childs of the direct childs, they didn't match the selector anymore.

I added the `.stack__inner` so that the elements you want the margin-top on are contained in a precisely defined element.

```css
.stack .stack__inner > * + * {
  margin-top: var(--stack-gap);
}
```

```html
<div class="stack" style="--stack-gap:20px">
  <div class="stack__inner">
    <div>...</div>
    <div>...</div>
  </div>
  <div class="stack" style="--stack-gap:60px">
    <div class="stack__inner">
      <div>...</div>
      <div>...</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: My bad I had that inmind while writing the answer, but it doesn't actually make it easily readable. Actually, it solves the selector problem you had, I'll edit my question to cover that.

Answer (score -1):

You can do this. This will work on every element after the first

```
:root {
  --stack-gap: 20px;
}

.stack > div:not(:first-child) {
  margin-top: var(--stack-gap);
}
```

also works

```
<div class="stack" style="--stack-gap:20px">
    <div>...</div>
    <div>...</div>
</div>
<style>
    .stack>div:not(:first-child) {
        margin-top: var(--stack-gap);
    }
</style>
```